# No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page on Windows App Save

Tags: c#, wpf, encoding, appx

I have a UWP app that I am deploying as an AppPackage, and I am seeing an off error when I attempt to read/save a file in the LocalState folder. It does not happen everytime, so I am thinking the file is locked during the process at some point. The erroe is

> No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

And the code that throws the error

```
private const string SETTINGS_FILENAME = "settings.json";
private static readonly StorageFolder _settingsFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
public async static Task<ConfigWrapper> LoadSettings()
{
    try
    {
        StorageFile sf = await _settingsFolder.GetFileAsync(SETTINGS_FILENAME);
        if (sf == null) return null;

        string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sf, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigWrapper>(content);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        DiagnosticsClient.TrackException(e);
        return null;
    }
}

public async static Task<bool> SaveSettings(ConfigWrapper data)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await _settingsFolder.CreateFileAsync(SETTINGS_FILENAME, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { });
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, content, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        DiagnosticsClient.TrackException(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am making sure to save and read the file in UTF-8, so I am not sure why there would be an encoding error. Is there something I need to do (lock the file for instance) when I save/read?

Comment: Please find a way to dump the offending text in hex.

Comment: You want the unreadable file? Here is before and after

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1f61dFl0XAxXQ7xTN2rSvGo5SdNjeaMXo?usp=drive_open

Comment: The "before" file is not JSON, not unicode, not messed up UTF-8, not hex, not anything that I recognize.  If you are running on a Unix server, do `file filename` to see if it can deduce, via its "magic", what it is.

Comment: The before file IS a json file, what do you say it's not?

Comment: I am running on Windows, hence wpf. The code shows I am saving a json file as utf8 but it is getting corrupted somehow

Comment: @IsaacLevin - Sorry, I had them swapped.  Yes, "before" is JSON; "after" is in no format that I recognize.

Answer (score -1):

Many applications save data in a proprietary format.  The gibberish you provided is probably such.

Such applications often have a way to "write" or "export" or "save as" the data.  Look for such.

Comment: I am saving the file as utf8 json myself in code. It is getting corrupted somehow

Comment: @IsaacLevin - Can you "print" it and/or dump the beginning of it in Hex?

Comment: Print what? The file format should never change. But occasionally when I view the file it looks like after, which is not json. I am trying to figure out what is causing it.